# Legend inconsistent in QGIS map print layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

After I did styling my vector data set to be classified by graduated circle and categorized by type, it appears beautifully consistent in the map canvas as shown below:
[image: The style show in layer panel is consistent]

But when I create a print map layout and after adding the map, I add the legend and it come out ugly inconsistent like this:
[image: The Legend added in the map print layout is inconsistent]

So, I would like to ask for help to make the legend in the map print layout consistent as the legend shown in layer panel.
I use the latest version QGIS 3.10.2 64bit.

Comment: Please consider using a different visualization option, e.g. labelling the data, using a colour-ramp, or (rather non-intuitive) different symbols. Your current visualization method is unsuited for creating a proper map.

Answer (score 2):

**This issue can be split into two parts.** The one regarding the "broken legend-lines not aligning" I will adress below and which is already fixed, and the second one regarding NULL values you can read up here: [How to make symbols visible in legend in Layout?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/378556/107424). The second one seems to be partially intended *(I strongly disagree this should be intended though: What if I dont want to display points with nodata, which is a quite common case?)*, but however, there is a "workaround" provided on [GitHub](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39882) and [GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/378712/107424).

The part with the "broken legend lines not aligning" is already fixed. See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34166. I recommend to update to QGIS 3.10.12 or later to fix this issue. Alternatively you can use 3.8 or below, or as a poor workaround, if the above is absolutely not an option, create a screenshot of the correct legend and add it to the print layout as image.

Comment: do you know whether the issue has been resolved already? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @MaxMuller its fixed.

Comment: Really? It does not seem like that when I try it.

Comment: QGIS version 3.10

Comment: Which 3.10? Try the latest 3.10.12

Comment: Still an issue when null is 0 and legend reprensentation always have a null size of 0 if unchanged. Tickets are closed since they are often duplicates.

Comment: @Alrl yes, this discussion also already exists here on GIS SE and refers to a "different" issue then the one I originally adressed on this question here. This also lead to parts of your linked github issue. I still strongly disagree this behavior should be intended though. Please also check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/378556/107424. However, it seems like both issues belong together. So I have reworded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue but there are no perfect way to solve this right now. And it is partly intended. Just set a size when Null as per https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39882#issuecomment-723669783