# How to make symbols visible in legend in Layout?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, legend

I have followed the steps for creating proportional symbol and multivariate analysis ([QGIS docs](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#proportional-symbol-and-multivariate-analysis)).
It looks like expected in the canvas and in the Legend Items-window in "Item properties"-tab in the Layout.

However, the symbols are not visible in the legend in the map.
How may I make the symbols visible also here?

I'm using QGIS ver. 3.16.0.

[image]

Comment: Do they show if you widen the legend frame on your map?  You might play around with some of the Item Properties for the legend such as spacing, position and size including the reference point.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, nothing did the trick so far?!?

Comment: Looks like a bug, I could reproduce that one on 3.16.0, 3.14.15, 3.10.11 and 3.4.12 on Win64bit versions. Please report it on https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues. Meanwhile you need to find a workaround, e.g. use diagrams with a similar styling or use an image as legend..

Comment: @MrXsquared, thanks for the effort in earlier versions abd for the link. I have now reported it as a possible bug.

Comment: It seems to be ok in version 3.14.16 (Windows 10) according to a comment to the filed bug-report: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hurray, it's not a bug.

It is possible to make the symbols visible in the Layout.

See my detailed answer to this post [I style points in QGIS 3.10.2 with two different attributes BUT the legend symbol is not visible in Layout composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376022/i-style-points-in-qgis-3-10-2-with-two-different-attributes-but-the-legend-symbo/378656#378656).

The main point being setting a minimum value greater than zero when null.

[image]

See the clue given by @gioman here in the bug report [Symbols from multivariate analysis not visible in legend in Layout #39882](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39882)

Comment: Good to know. But still sounds like a bug to me. What if I dont want to display points with nodata, which is a quite common case? (rhetorical question)